# Spring @Autowire field based on @Profile

Tags: spring, spring-profiles

I need to autowire fields based on the `spring.profiles.active` property.
The service is only created based on the profile but the since the service is autowired in other classes I am unable to use the @Profile annotations.

Is there a way to autowire fields based on profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can create different services implementations per profiles.

In the example below I used mockito to mock the dataSource bean

Ex.

```
 @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    class YourConfig {

        @Profile("production")
        @Qualifier("datasource")
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSourceProduction(){
           return new DataSourceProduction()
        }

        @Profile("development")
        @Qualifier("datasource")
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSourceDevelopment(){
           return mock(DataSourceProduction.class);
        }
```

Comment: Wanted to avoid creating a mock.But thanks i guess I would have to do the same.

Comment: depending on what you're trying to accomplish you don't have to create a mock like this... but the original question is unclear enough to call this wrong.

Comment: The question is how to tell spring: hey spring autowire this field in my class only when profile X is activated.